# How can I scale the channel range for a servo output in betaflight?

Tags: betaflight, servo

I have a servo linked to an aux channel in Betaflight which turns from -45 to 45 degrees as the channel value goes from 1000 to 2000. I want it to turn in a smaller range (from -9 to 9 degrees) with the same signal range on the aux channel. Essentially, I want the servo output to be the channel value scaled by a factor of 1/5.

I applied the following configuration:

```
feature SERVO_TILT
servo 0 1400 1600 1500 20 4
```

[image]

However, with this configuration the servo value is simply clipped to the target range: e.g. if the channel value goes above 1600, the servo output stays at 1600. The rate setting (20%, which I assume should give me the factor 1/5 scaling) seems to be completely ignored. How can I get the scaling to work?